# send forms with drag and drop saving width php

Tags: php, jquery, html, drag

I wanted to do the following when the draggable element was dragged into a div would run a submit in javascript to save this action, as this example: http://html5demos.com/drag

Answer (score 0):

Bind to `dragstop` event and do ajax within handler